# What does "Non-Carbon CFM" mean?

Tags: macos, macos-carbon

In a number of API calls, the header file says:

```
Mac OS X:         in version 10.0 and later in Carbon.framework
CarbonLib:        in CarbonLib 1.1 and later
Non-Carbon CFM:   not available
```

What do "CarbonLib" and "Non-Carbon CFM" mean?  Does that mean I can use this function, or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're developing for Mac OS X (a.k.a. OS X, a.k.a. macOS), you should refer to the first line. The other two lines are not relevant for you or, really, these days, anybody.

So, yes, you can use the function, assuming there's nothing else in the header indicating you can't or shouldn't (like not being available for 64-bit or being deprecated).

CarbonLib and Non-Carbon CFM were relevant for classic Mac OS. The "CFM" in Non-Carbon CFM refers to the [Code Fragment Manager](http://mirror.informatimago.com/next/developer.apple.com/documentation/mac/PPCSoftware/PPCSoftware-41.html), which is basically a dynamic loader. The modern analog would be dyld.

Comment: With `import Carbon`, it does indeed work.  Am I remembering correctly that Apple never made Carbon 64-bit?  Or is this function calling a 32-bit library from a 64-bit application?

Comment: The parts of Carbon about UI (windows, menus, etc.) was never available for 64-bit (except briefly in a pre-release seed). Some other pieces were/are, usually ones for which there isn't a Cocoa equivalent available. Also, there's some stuff that used to be thought of as part of Carbon which is now called CarbonCore and is part of the CoreServices framework.